# TypeError: socket.listen is not a function

Tags: node.js

```
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
res.end('hey!');
});

server.listen(3000);

const io = socketio.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('Kullanıcı bağlandı.');

});
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Kullanıcı ayrıldı.');
});
```

[image]

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Good luck 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// extract only our needed constructor from the socket.io library
const { Server } = require('socket.io'); 

// Construct a socket
const io = new Server(server);

// Bind the socket to your created http server.
io.listen(server);
```

Some usefull documentation for you : https://socket.io/get-started/chat